# How to build .appx file for Windows 8.1 Phone app, in Visual Studio Express?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I've finished developing my first windows-phone-silverlight app and tested it on the emulator successfully then created a paid developer account and now I'm in the stage of uploading my app file, the store is expecting a .appx file, but in Visual Studio Express 2013 the "Store" menu contains only "Launch Windows App Certification Kit"

[image]

How do I get the rest of the options or I'd like to know if there's another way to export such extension, I can only see a .xap file in the bin/release folder of the project, but the store isn't accepting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might accidentally be in the windows store instead of windows phone store.The two are integrated now.Just make sure you submit the xap in the windows phone store and it should be accepted.

Comment: The appx and appxupload are the binaries which Windows store accepts.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I thought both were the same

Answer (score 0):

If your project is Windows Phone Silverght 8.1, You don't need to build .appx file. Because it's for Windows Phone 8.1. You just need to publish it with the xap file like Windows Phone 8.0.

Comment: I just test it. The windows phone store can receive xap file. The OpenFileDialog can receive appx,appxbundle,appxupload and xap file.

Comment: it's giving me error you can only upload "appx or appxbundle"

Comment: I'm now rewriting the app as Windows 8.1 phone app not Windows Phone Silverlight app